# string manipulation in python

Tags: python

I have a python file like this

```
import urllib2

try:
    data = urllib2.urlopen('http:....').read()
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print "HTTP error: %d" % e.code
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print "Network error: %s" % e.reason.args[1]

print data1
```

the output looks like this

```
>>>
15.95

>>>
```

I need to perform some manipulation of data1 (or any alternate variable) so that when I print data1 (or the new variable) the output does not have the extra line. In other words I want it to look like this:

```
>>>
15.95
>>>
```

Any help would be great I am relatively new to python. I have been screwing around with \r and cannot seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you just need to strip whitespace from your variable? Use `data1.strip()`. Read up on  [str.strip()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) for more information.

By the way, to see the whitespace explicitly, use `print repr(data1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip).

Answer (score 1):

```
data1.strip()
```

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip

> "Return a copy of the string with
>   leading and trailing characters
>   removed."

Answer (score 0):

you can also use [rstrip()](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.rstrip) if all you want to do is get rid of extra stuff on the right side